# HTML parser in .Net

Tags: .net, parsing, open-source, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

I am looking for open source .Net HTML parser. It should be open source, because I have to do some changes. Googling I ve found Majestic, anyway, I wish to know some good alternatives to choose one that can be easily customized.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open source .Net HTML parsers don't get much better than [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [HTML AGILITY PACK](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)

Answer (score 0):

[Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: HTML Agility hasn't been touched in 2 years - it is dated now.

Comment: @DaveGordon is there a better option?

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich there are a number of options... whether they are better or not is down to individual preference. However, CsQuery provides HTML5 & CSS3 compatibility.